# I'm getting a T_VARIABLE error from route.php , Codeigniter framework

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm adding this code to `config/route.php`

```
 $route['news/create'] = 'news/create';
 $route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
 $route['news'] = 'news';
```

As I added this files to the `application/views/` to work , is that was a right code for the following files?

```
views /news/create.php
views/news/view.php
views/news/index.php
```

I use Codeigniter, and I get a syntax error of `unexpected T_VARIABLE` from my ftp.

Comment: Routes call controller files and its functions and in controller you can call view

Comment: I tried with $route['news'] = 'news'; and my controller was News.php it didn't work?

Comment: `$route['news'] = 'news';` will call the index function of news controller. Have a look of this https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html

Comment: The code is fine, this looks like a syntax error

Comment: routing effects **controllers** not *views* so I'm not sure why you are showing us your routes and view files.

Comment: People are right, your routes will be resolved by controllers. Can you share more of the error?